# JQuery Require Checkbox and Radio Button before submit

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am having one heck of a hard time trying to figure this out. Been looking at examples and tools for JQuery validation for over 3 hours now.

All I want to do is require that a checkbox is selected and a radio button, but I don't care which one is required.

```
<form id="form1" action="/controller/action" method="post">
    <div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="box1" class="cBox" /><label for="box1" class="label">Box1</label></div>
    <div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="Box2" class="cBox" /><label for="Box2" class="label">Box2</label></div>
    <div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="Box3" class="cBox" /><label for="Box3" class="label">Box3</label></div>
    <div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="print" value="Radio1" class="rad" /><label class="label">Radio1</label></div>
    <div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="print" value="Radio2" class="rad" /><label class="label">Radio2</label></div>
    <div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="print" value="Radio3" class="rad" /><label class="label">Radio3</label></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To do this you have to use the [`:checked`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checked) selector. Although JP's answer is fine, I'd probably do this:

```
$('#form1').submit(function() {
    if ($('input:checkbox', this).is(':checked') &&
        $('input:radio', this).is(':checked')) {
        // everything's fine...
    } else {
        alert('Please select something!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Couple of notes:

- I think it reads better to use the [`is`](http://docs.jquery.com/Is) function, which returns a boolean of the selector.
- You can use [`:radio`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/radio) and [`:checkbox`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checkbox) as a shortcut for selecting all radios and checkboxes in a form. However, [according to the jQuery manual](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checkbox), it is bad practice to use these selectors without specifying `input` before them, as they evaluate to `*:checkbox` and `*:radio` otherwise, which are very slow selectors.
- By passing `this` as the second argument we are [specifying a context](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#expressioncontext) for the search, and thus are only searching for checkboxes and radio inputs inside the current form. Without it we might get false positives if there happens to be another form in the page.

Comment: Thank you I am glad to know that as I am going to have a couple other forms on the page and this helps with that. And the answer is still simple.

Comment: doesn't this code make every checkbox and radio button required? Edit: nevermind, I thought we were looping through the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#form1').submit(function(){
    if ($(':checkbox:checked', this)[0] && $(':radio:checked', this)[0]) {
        // everything's fine...
    } else {
        alert('Please select something!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I feel like such an idiot now.  That is sooo simple. I'm going to go bang my head on a wall for a while now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. You also forgot the input before the :radio and :checkbox. It is not recommended by the manual to use them without that.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in my case where I want to require users to check a checkbox in order to submit a form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#yourinput').required = true;
});
```